# Android parse Object KSOAP

Tags: java, android, parsing, ksoap2

I'd like to know how do I parse the output of SOAP. My current code is the following:

```
try{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();   

    Log.e("Output:", response.toString());

}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("Error:", e.getCause().toString());
}
```

The output of the response is this:

> [{"category_id":767,"parent_id":663,"name":"Walk"},
>   {"category_id":768,"parent_id":767,"name":"Google"},
>   {"category_id":764,"parent_id":697,"name":"Yellow"}]

So, how do I get these values separately?

I just want to let you know that If I change this line:

```
Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
```

To this:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

I get the following error:

```
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.WebExample/com.example.WebExample.SyncActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at 
com.example.WebExample.SyncActivity.onCreate(SyncActivity.java:49)
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-01 11:28:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4600):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is line 49 `SyncActivity.java`?

Comment: It's the name of my activity.

Comment: line 49 pls soemthing on that line is null

Comment: Yes, that line had an error. I changed from: `Log.e("Error:", e.getCause().toString());`, to `Log.e("Error:", e.toString());`. Now I get the following error: 
10-01 11:43:29.086: E/Error:(9180): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

With this code: `SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();`

Comment: Your response is a string you are casting it to soapobject.

Comment: You are right again. I changed to: `SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;` and now I'm able to show the output with SoapObject, with: `Log.e("output:", rep.getPropertyAsString(0));`
Although, I haven't reach yet what I want (get the specific values from array).

Comment: Its s json array you get you need to parse the same now

Comment: Can you guide me? I'm trying but I can't reach there.

Comment: Try the code in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments you need to parse the json array.

```
 JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("jsonstring");
 for(int i =0 ; i< jr.length();i++)
 {
 JSONObject jb =(JSONObject) jr.get(i);  
 String categoryid = jb.getString("category_id");
 String parent_id = jb.getString("parent_id");
 String name = jb.getString("name");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to **@Raghunandan**. Also, it retrieves the right encoding, which is awesome, since that json_encode put special characters on strings.

```
try{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

    JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0));
    for(int i =0 ; i< jr.length();i++)
     {
         JSONObject jb =(JSONObject) jr.get(i);  

         String name = jb.getString("name");
         Log.e("value:", name);
     }

}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("Error:", e.toString());
}
```